# Operating on files in current directory and putting them into new directory

Tags: python, file, directory

I am currently in a working directory where following files are present

```
abcde_file
gvmdgv_file
qst_file
rl.txt
qp.txt
trs_file
```

I want to do some operations on all files with _file at end and put them into a new directory called newdir.

My try:

```
from glob import glob
files = glob("*_file")

with open('newdir/{}'.format(files),'a') as a:
    with open(files,'r') as r:
        #required operations
```

It gives error saying file name too long for `with open('newdir/{}'.format(files),'a')`

Comment: *files* is a list of paths and you're passing it as a whole to the format string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because variable `files` is a list containing all matching files with _file as a suffix. You should loop through every single element of the list and copy it instead.
Something like this should work:

```
from glob import glob
files = glob("*_file")
for file in files:
    oldf = open(file,'r')
    newf = open(newdir+"\\"+file,'w+')
    data = oldf.read()
    newf.write(data)
oldf.close()
newf.close()
```

If you are copying files different than textfiles, you might want to open the two file handles with `rb` and `wb+` instead. Variable `newdir` could be a constant with the new directory path, for example.

Comment: could you help me out with that. I'm a newbie.

Comment: Instead of using ```newdir + file``` can I use ```newdir/file``` ?

Comment: No, you're concatenating strings, so you have to do it that way.

Comment: Actually I am creating the newdir in the same script so how do I find the path for newdir?

Comment: ``` os.mkdir('newdir') ```  this is what I'm using and directory of script keeps changing with usage so there is no definite path to newdir

Comment: ok I used ```with open('newdir/{}'.format(file1),'a') ``` and it worked. Thanks anyway for all the help

Comment: Even if newdir changes with time, you should have it in a variable which you can use when opening the file handle.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to have a look at python's native "high-level file operations" library [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html)

```py
import shutil

shutil.copy("filepath to copy", "path-to-destination-folder")
```

Comment: Hi , this will copy my files to the new directory but what about the operations I need to perform before sending them to the new directory?

Comment: oh... I might have over-read that...   then you might still want to use your initial approach but you have to loop over your `files` list as already suggested!